# How can yup string error paths be used without Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

When Yup is required for validating dynamic objects formik becomes near impossible to use. When executing the validate method on a Yup schema with the object to be validated and the object {abortEarly, false} like this:

`schema.validate(data, {abortEarly: false})`

You receive a list of errors inside err.inner. These error objects contain the reason for the error and the error path. How can you parse these errors and determine from the paths which items have an error and which don't.